# What is the expectation of a Gaussian PDF?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, density-function

For $X \sim N(x|\mu,\sigma)$ with probability density function $p(x)$, what is $E[p(x)]$?

Comment: Please also read the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) before modifying your question

Comment: @Glen_b ok so I wrongly understood the `self-study` tag, I didn't get this from a textbook or something, I'm actually writing a program that would use this result, so would it be fine if i just remove the `self-study` tag?

Comment: @Glen_b I added this tag because I was told before that this tag might be helpful for some entry-level questions (and it really is) here (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199298/where-is-wrong-with-my-formulation-of-estimating-the-probability-of-a-biased-coi

Comment: You'd likely be asked to add the tag for any routine textbook-style question, which (say) might be set as an exercise (which this certainly qualifies for). If you had not done so I'd have asked you to add it anyway. Asking about concepts is fine, as is seeking some level of guidance to a solution -- for example, the guidance "use the law of the unconscious statistician to write the expectation as an integral, combine the exponents giving a single squared term, recognize the Gaussian density, pull extra constants out the front of the integral; the density integrates to 1" should be okay

Comment: That's basically the answer you have, except it describes each step rather than give the explicit algebraic terms. If you're only interested in the *answer* and not the steps, it's a standard result readily obtained with a little googling. For example, $\int \phi(x)^2dx$ is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) which (up to a linear rescaling and substitution of the limits to get the definite integral is the answer below)

Comment: However, if you could explain the application in your question a bit further there might be some argument to remove the tag and reopen (in spite of it then spoiling the value of a lot of future student's assignments)

Comment: In any case, I'll reopen for now; there may be little point in keeping it closed at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an easier way to do this using properties of the Normal distribution, but I present a direct answer from the definition of expectation. The pdf of $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is

$$p(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left(-\dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) $$

The expectation of the pdf is then
\begin{align*}
E[p(x)] & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left(-\dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left(-\dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dx\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}  \exp \left(-2\dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dx\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2/2}} \exp \left(-\dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2/2} \right) dx\\
& = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}},
\end{align*}

where the last step is because the integrand is the pdf for a $N(\mu, \sigma^2/2)$ random variable.

Comment: and for multivariate Gaussians this would be $(4\pi)^{D/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}$ right?

Comment: Please note that for `self-study` questions, the [requested behavior](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) is to provide hints and guidance to lead the asker in the correct direction rather than provide a complete solution.

Comment: I mean the denominator.