# What does beta distribution "has support" mean?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/199312/255062) says

> the beta prior has support over all valid probabilities and only over
>   valid probabilities

About `Support`, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) says

> In mathematics, the support of a real-valued function f is the subset
>   of the domain containing those elements which are not mapped to zero.
>   If the domain of f is a topological space, the support of f is instead
>   defined as the smallest closed set containing all points not mapped to
>   zero. This concept is used very widely in mathematical analysis.

What does beta distribution "has support" mean here? Can anyone give an example to illustrate this? Such as this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/199298/255062)

Comment: It's just imprecise use of prepositions, which is a foible of the English language. Most prepositions can be used nearly interchangeably without a tremendous loss of meaning. More precisely, "The support of a beta prior is all valid probabilities".

Comment: To be "supported over" a set means to have non-zero density over the aforementioned set.

Comment: You're referring to the wrong section of the Wikipedia article: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory instead.

Comment: @Demetri: Roughly, but formally it refers to the closure of the set of values with non-zero density.  (Noting that we can change any countable number of values in a continuous density to zero and it is still a valid density for the distribution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better read this way:

> the beta prior has and only has support over all valid probabilities

However, I think it is a bit redundant in terms of its meaning?

Answer (score 4):

For a single probability parameter, the interval $\mathscr{P} \equiv [0,1]$ is the set of "all valid probabilities and only valid probabilities".  Thus, when they say that the Beta distribution "has support over" $\mathscr{P}$, what they mean is that for any random variable $p \sim \text{Beta}$ we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(p \in \mathscr{P}) &= 1, \\[6pt]
\mathbb{P}(p \in \mathscr{S}) &<1 \text{ for every closed (measureable) set } \mathscr{S} \subset \mathscr{P}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In other words, the interval $\mathscr{P}$ is the smallest closed set containing $p$ with probability one.  Informally, this can be thought of as the closure of the set of possible values of $p$.  (Note that the same reasoning occurs for the Dirichlet distribution when you extend to a probability vector.)  The support can also be thought of as the closure of the set of values with non-zero density, so another way to think of the support here is that:

$$\mathscr{P} = \text{cl} \{ p \in \mathbb{R} | \text{Beta}(p|\alpha,\beta) > 0 \}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide a non-technical answer to your question.

The beta distribution is commonly used in the context of modeling *proportions*.

As an example, let’s say you select (at random) 100 geographic sites for a study and you keep track for each site what proportion of the site’s area can be classified as “forest”.  (If 20% of the area of the first site can be classified as “forest”, the proportion of interest is 0.20, etc.)

If you denote by X the random variable defined as “proportion of site’s area that can be classified as a forest”, then you might want to assume that X follows a beta distribution.

What does it mean that this beta distribution has a support of (0,1)?

It simply means that the possible values of X span the interval (0,1). In particular, the 100 realized values of X collected in your study would all be expected to be strictly greater than 0 and strictly less than 1.

This is fine if you selected your sites so as to always include a mixture of forest and grasses.

But what if you’re interested in sites which might be all forest, all grasses or a combination of both?

Then you might have to model X via a zero-and-one inflated beta distribution, whose support is the interval [0,1]. In that case, the support of the distribution of X tells you that the possible values of X could live anywhere inside the interval [0,1] (including at the edges of this interval). For the example of with 100 sites, this might mean that a fraction of those sites would have no forest on them, a fraction would have some forest and a fraction would have only forest on them.